# How to add frequency count labels to the bars in a bar graph using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I want to plot frequency distribution of an [r] factor variable as a bargraph, where bars represent the frequency counts of the factor levels. I use ggplot2 to do that and there's no problem with that.

What I can't figure out is how to add frequency count labels to the bars in the bargraph. The syntax that I've tried is as follows:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = factorvar)) + geom_bar(fill = "somecolor") + geom_text(aes(y = ???))
```

I think I thoroughly searched in stackoverflow and "R Graphics Cookbook" by W.Chang but I couldn't find any specific answer to what parameter should I match to "y" in the aesthetics of geom_text() above. I tried some variants like: (y = ..count..) but it didn't work.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks...

Comment: From some partial notes for this question, the example given was   geom_text(aes(label = numbers), vjust=-1, position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3) # try numbers

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=clarity)) +
geom_bar() +
geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: For me, it worked with `stat='count'`

Comment: `Stat = "count"` worked for me as well.  The error says `StatBin` requires a continuous variable, but I have categorical variables.

Comment: What is you use the "fill = variable" option, and only want the total count over the bars?

Comment: I get this warning: `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.

Comment: I got an error saying "stat_count requires the following missing aesthetics: x"

Comment: ggplot2 version 3.3.0 now supports `geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count)), vjust = -1)`

Comment: If you want to use `geom_label`: `geom_label(stat="count", aes(label=format(after_stat(count), big.mark = ",")))`. I don't know if this calculates the counts twice, once for `geom_bar` and once for the labels...