# How to display counts on a stacked barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I've run this code. Giving the results displayed. I now want to add count numbers for each individual category of each stacked bar.

```
dat$SU<-as.factor(dat$SU) 
#INVENTORY PER SU
ggplot(dat, aes(x=SU,fill=factor(SCIENTIFIC_NAME)))+
  geom_bar(width=0.5)+xlab("Sampling Unit (SU)")+
  ylab("Count")+labs(fill="SCIENTIFIC NAME")+
  ggtitle("Inventory per sampling unit (SU) by species")+ 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,15))
```

[image: stacked barplot per su]

Comment: Hi OP, have you seen the answers posted to these questions?  [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553526/how-to-add-frequency-count-labels-to-the-bars-in-a-bar-graph-using-ggplot2).  [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551921/show-frequencies-along-with-barplot-in-ggplot2).

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you can provide some data. In meantime you can try something like this:

```
 df %>%
  count(SU, SCIENTIFIC_NAME) %>%
  group_by(SU) %>%
  mutate(y_pos = rev(n/2) + cumsum(c(0, head(rev(n), -1)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = SU)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = n, fill = factor(SCIENTIFIC_NAME))) + 
    geom_text(aes(y = y_pos, label = n)) +
 ...
```

Counting before `ggplot` and using `geom_col` (its same as `geom_bar` with `stat = identity`) and adding `geom_text` for adding text. `...`  represent rest of code u want to add.